# Constructing Group Divisible Designs - Algorithms?

Tags: co.combinatorics, combinatorial-designs

I am starting my research on group divisible designs this year and I wonder if there are any algorithms/software that help with constructions.

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

There are some implementations available in sagemath, see e.g. http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/combinat/sage/combinat/designs/group_divisible_designs.html#sage-combinat-designs-group-divisible-designs